# Video uploading error instagram api mgp25

Tags: php, laravel-5, instagram-api

I am using instagram api to upload image and video, image is being posted and working fine but the problem is with video uploading. throwing this exeption.
in the controller image post is working but video post is not working.

error is.
JsonMapper::map() requires first argument to be an object, NULL given

my ajax uploading method is.

```
if($('#iCheck').is(':checked')){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'instagram/write',
            data:{
                'caption':status,
                'image':image,
                'video':video
            },
            success:function (data) {
                count = count - 1;
                if (count == 0) {
                    loading.hide(100);
                }


                if (data == 'success') {
                    $('#iMsgSu').show(300);
                }
                else {
                    $('#iMsgEr').html(data);
                    $('#iMsgEr').show(300);
                }
                console.log(data);
                count = count - 1;
                if (count == 0) {
                    loading.hide(100);
                    var sentData = fbId + '_' + twId + '_' + tuId + '_' + wpId;
                    postSave(sentData);
                    $('#final').val(sentData);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

my controller method is.

```
public function write(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $image = $request->image;
            $video = $request->video;

            if ( $image ) {
                $this->instagram->uploadPhoto(public_path() . "/uploads/" . $request->image, $request->caption);
            }
            if ( $video ) {
                $this->instagram->uploadVideo(public_path() . "/uploads/videos/" . $request->video, $request->caption);
            }
            return "success";
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return $exception->getMessage();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is your server's upload limit? Check your apache/nginx configs, as well as your php.ini - what's the value?

Comment: Server upload limit is 30 MB whereas the file size i am trying to upload is 5 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `ffprobebin` and `ffmpeg` to upload Video via `mgp25` instagram API.

```
\InstagramAPI\Utils::$ffprobeBin = 'Directory\Instagram-Project\FFmpeg\ffprobe.exe';
\InstagramAPI\Utils::$ffmpegBin = 'Directory\Instagram-Project\FFmpeg\ffmpeg.exe';
```

if you want php example I can send.

Comment: can you send me, please? jabbasov020@gmail.com